# Access data in class between two classes C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem, that I need to access data in class, that I inserted in another class.
Example is following:

Program calls out functions as following:

```
static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // ...
            InsertData.Insert();
            GetData.Read();
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Here I am keeping my data:

```
public class DataFromADVM
{
   private ObservableCollection<DataFromAD> _ADData;

    public ObservableCollection<DataFromAD> ADData
    {
        get { return _ADData; }
        set { _ADData = value; }
    }

    public DataFromADVM()
    {
        this._ADData = new ObservableCollection<DataFromAD>();
    }

    internal void AddDataFromAD(DataFromAD dataFromAd)
    {
        _ADData.Add(dataFromAd);
    }
}
```

Inserting data:

```
public class InsertData
{
    DataFromADVM _DataVm = new DataFromADVM();
    public void Insert()
    {
        DataFromAD dataFromAd = new DataFromAD();
        dataFromAd.Id = 0;
        dataFromAd.Key = "name";
        dataFromAd.Value = "Peeter";
        _DataVm.AddDataFromAD(dataFromAd);
    }
}
```

Reading data:

```
public class GetData
{
   public void Read()
   {
      // if I create new ViewModel here, then data will be empty
      // how could I access to ADData in DataFromADVM in this class?
   }
}
```

Comment: i guess you can use DataContext property of your View, just make sure that your DataContext is of type DataFromADVM. and no need to create new ViewModel

Comment: Why is read in a dfferent class and not a methof on `DataFromADVM`?

Comment: There is a big smell in this code: Any class that is named after a verb is suspect to be wrong. You have two of those.

Comment: you can use same object of class DataFromADVM to insert and read the data. I think you are inserting and reading from different classes and your DataFromADVM object is disposed before you read.

Comment: Class names are for example, I don't use them in my program that way.

Can I prevent DataFromADVM of being disposed?

Comment: If instance X needs something from instance Y, then X must have a reference to Y, or some means of getting a reference.  This is basic stuff, here.  It also has nothing to do with MVVM or xaml.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a reference to the instance you are trying to read form, otherwise the class will not know from which instance you are trying ot read, even if there is only one instance.....

you can init the `GetData` class with a reference to `DataFromADVM` if you create

```
DataFromADVM _data;
 public GetData(DataFromADVM data)
        {
            _data = data;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Comment: As I understand, then with this example I need to return and send `data` value.
In console application I have method, where I call those functions out in different classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could get a reference to your ViewModel by locating it like this:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;
public class GetData {
    DataFromADVM _data;
    public GetData() {
        _data = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<DataFromADVM>();
    }
}
```

How it works:
The connection between *View* and *ViewModel* will be setup with a *ViewModelLocator*. There on creation of a *View* set the *DataContext* to the Locator

```
DataContext="{Binding RandomName, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

In the *Locator* all your used *ViewModel*s bound to a *View* will get registered and  properties provide the reference:

```
public class ViewModelLocator {
    static ViewModelLocator() {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<DataFromADVM>();
    }
    public RandomName DataFromADVM {
        get {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<DataFromADVM>();
        }
    }
}
```

If you dont want to set this all up yourself, try the [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.mvvmlight.net/creating/) or similar kits.

Comment: How this should work? Because currently I am getting NullReference with your example.

Comment: I tried to provide a way to get you rolling with this. But you might simply try MVVM Light with the Example Project and have a look on how the MainView got connected to its ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got the solution thanks to some of the comments and research:

```
static class Program
    {
        Static DataFromADVM _vm
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // ...
            _vm = InsertData.Insert();
            GetData.Read(_vm);
            // ...
        }
    }


public class InsertData
{
    DataFromADVM _DataVm = new DataFromADVM();
    public static DataFromADVM Insert()
    {
        DataFromAD dataFromAd = new DataFromAD();
        dataFromAd.Id = 0;
        dataFromAd.Key = "name";
        dataFromAd.Value = "Peeter";
        _DataVm.AddDataFromAD(dataFromAd);
    }
    return _DataVm;
}


public class GetData
    {
       public void Read()
       {
          var checkList = _vm.ADData.Count;
            return checkList;
       }
    }
```